# Use SSH private key as an RSA private key for decrypting data encrypted with public key

Tags: go, encryption, ssh, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to use the system's SSH Pub and Private Keys to encrypt and decrypt data (strings, etc) in Go.

I have been able to successfully encrypt data using the SSH Public Key as an RSA Public Key. However, I am unable to use the same/similar approach while trying to decrypt the same data with the SSH Private Key (attempting to use it as an RSA private key)

### Encryption code - That works

```
func EncryptWithPublicKey(pubKeyLoc string, symCipherText bytes.Buffer) ([]byte, error) {
//read file first
pub, err := ioutil.ReadFile(pubKeyLoc)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

parsed, _, _, _, err := ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(pub)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

parsedCryptoKey := parsed.(ssh.CryptoPublicKey)
pubCrypto := parsedCryptoKey.CryptoPublicKey()
rsaPub := pubCrypto.(*rsa.PublicKey)

encryptedBytes, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(sha256.New(), rand.Reader, rsaPub, symCipherText.Bytes(), nil)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return encryptedBytes, nil
```

### Decryption code - Not working!

```
func DecryptWithPrivateKey(privPath string, wrappedData []byte) ([]byte, error) {
priv, err := ioutil.ReadFile(privPath)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

block, _ := pem.Decode(priv)
der, err := x509.DecryptPEMBlock(block, []byte(""))
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

privKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(der)

// dec, err := ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey(priv)
// if err != nil {
//  return nil, err
// }

// parsedKey := dec.(*rsa.PrivateKey)

decryptBytes, err := privKey.Decrypt(nil, wrappedData, &rsa.OAEPOptions{Hash: crypto.SHA256})
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return decryptBytes, nil
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

#### update - answered below

before I found the solution, I had two errors

- decryption error OR
- non-DEK Info found in header error

They have been addressed in the solution

Comment: In general, saying something is not working is not particularly useful. How do you know it's not working? Are you receiving some error message? Are you getting incorrect answers? The more details you provide the more likely you are to get a good answer.

Comment: "SSH key" is not a kind of key. Your SSH key is (these days) most likely an RSA key, so using it "as" an RSA key is just using it - more accurately, you have an RSA key, and you happen to be using it for SSH. But to Polk's point, we need to know what specifically the problem you're having is beyond "not working".

Comment: Yes, I get that the SSH key is an RSA key. But in this case, I am using it to distinguish between using it as an RSA key in Go. The error I am getting is a decryption error when I attempt to decrypt the encrypted payload and when I parse the pem and use it as a PKCS1 key, I get a “No DEK-info header in block”

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue.

Turns out, I was doing a few things wrong.

1. I hadnt factored base64 encoding when I was trying to decrypt (d'uh)
2. But more importantly, I didnt properly parse the Private Key I was trying use to decrypt the encrypted payload.

Here's the code:

```
func DecryptWithPrivateKey(privPath string, wrappedData []byte) ([]byte, error) {
//read private key
priv, err := ioutil.ReadFile(privPath)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

privKey, err := ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey(priv)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

//get raw encrypted payload
data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(wrappedData))
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

//parse the OpenSSH key as an RSA Private Key
parsedKey := privKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
decryptBytes, err := rsa.DecryptOAEP(sha256.New(), rand.Reader, parsedKey, data, nil)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return decryptBytes, nil
}
```